# How to filter key values from map using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a map like

```
contractAttributesMap=new HashMap<String,WsContractAttribute>();
contractAttributesMap.put("entityDisplayName", new WsContractAttribute("label_contractmap_entityDisplayName","entityDisplayName",WsContractAttribute.AttriibuteType.TEXT));
contractAttributesMap.put("entityNumber",new WsContractAttribute("label_contractmap_entityNumber","entityNumber",WsContractAttribute.AttriibuteType.TEXT));
//other code
```

I want to fetch values from list of key like having key list i.e.  List of key name.

I know one way

```
private static List<WsContractAttribute> getContractAttributes(Set<String> fields){
          for(String fieldName:fields){
           contractAttributesMap.entrySet()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains(fieldName))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
          }


      }
```

But instead of loop I want to pass this list itself into stream api and that will filter matched valued and return list.
That is possible.!!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `fields.stream().map(contractAttributesMap::get).collect(toList())`?

Comment: yes thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

That will be done by as explained by @aioobe

```
  private static List<WsContractAttribute> getContractAttributes(Set<String> fields){
          List<WsContractAttribute> list=fields.stream().map(contractAttributesMap::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
          return list;
      }
```